# eslint linting .eslintrc.js itself

Tags: eslint

I have the following scripts and eslint rules in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "jest tests/** --coverage",
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier --check './**/*.ts'",
    "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc './**/*.ts' --write"
...
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --config .prettierrc './**/*.ts' --write",
      "prettier --check './**/*.ts'",
      "eslint './src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix"
    ]
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint-staged"
  ],
```

When I run `npm run lint` I do not get any errors. But when my pre-commit hook runs, I get an error on the `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
/.../api/.eslintrc.js
  1:15  error    Require statement not part of import statement                                        @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
```

The line of code it's referencing has the following:

```
const _path = require('path');
```

I know I can instrument the code to force eslint to ignore this. But I do not understand why eslint is parsing `.eslintrc.js` in the first place as it is not located in the `src` folder (it's on the root folder on the same level of `package.json`).

Comment: lint-staged doesn't use the lint script you've defined, it doesn't know you only want src covered. Use an .eslintignore for more consistent behaviour.